# How to upgrade a user's .NET version with install of desktop app

Tags: .net, wpf, installation, upgrade

What is the best way to automatically upgrade a user's .NET version with install of a WPF desktop application?

Specifically, I am trying to upgrade user machines from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 or 4.5 (as of yet undecided)

Comment: It depends.  What installer technology are you using for the installation of your WPF app?

Comment: You can't really "upgrade" from 3.5. You can just install 4.0 and 4.5. 3.5 will remain side-by-side installed with 4.x.

Comment: @DaveMarkle, assume that this is open for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab since you are using WPF. Are you using ClickOnce/Publish from Visual Studio?  If you right click on the project, select properties, and click the Publish tab, you'll see a Prerequisites button.  There you can set which Framework you require.

Comment: Will that require a separate user download?  Ideally, I want it packaged together on a disk.

Comment: There is a radio option below the prerequisites that specifies 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' - which when you publish, puts the installers in the same location as your application code, which can be a CD, UNC location, etc.